# How to access ymail in gmail completely?

Tags: email, gmail, yahoo

I am following the details provided here (http://email.about.com/od/gmailtips/qt/How-To-Access-Yahoo-Mail-In-Gmail.htm) to access my ymail in gmail.

But in the step “**Send mail through your SMTP server”**

I ma getting the following error.
Authentication failed. Please check your username/password.
[Server response: DNS Error: 4476320 DNS type 'aaaa' lookup of http://smtp.yahoo.in (http://smtp.yahoo.in) responded with code NXDOMAIN 4476320 DNS type 'a' lookup of http://smtp.yahoo.in (http://smtp.yahoo.in) responded with code NXDOMAIN code(0) ]

[image]
How to get rid off this.

PS: I have already turned on “**Allow apps that use less secure sign-in**”

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem when I was trying to configure the same.
Change the SMTP server settings to:  smtp.mail.yahoo.com

rest is ok. now you don't face any problem. happy forwarding